# How can we install webpack on Windows?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundles

I have installed webpack on Ubuntu using following command on terminal

```
npm install -g webpack
```

**How to install same on Windows?**

Comment: Its the same command on windows also

Comment: You do the same on Windows. You just need to use npm. Download an appropriate program, or use npm commands in your IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There's no difference**. You can run the exact same command in Windows, assuming you have NPM installed. If you don't, [follow this link](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows) to download and install it.

Comment: Okay, i will try the same on Windows

Comment: On windows just run `choco install nodejs`

Answer (score 2):

It is the same on windows, but you will need to have npm in your windows machine.
npm commands works the same way on windows and linux machine. If you want to install globally, use the flag "**-g**".

Answer (score 0):

In [Cmder](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cmder) with [chocolatey:](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=npm)

```
choco install nodejs
npm install -g webpack
```

Or if you want to have a zsh experience, install ubuntu from the windows store